# How can I print the following 2D array?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ** letters (int*arr, int nr_elem)
{
    char **mat=(char**)malloc( nr_elem * sizeof(char*));

    int max =0;
    for (int i =0; i<nr_elem;i++)
    {
        if( *(arr + i) > max)
            max = *(arr + i);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<nr_elem; i++)
    {
        *mat=(char*)malloc((*(arr+i))*sizeof(char));
    }

    for(int i=0; i<nr_elem;i++)
      {

      for(int j=0; j<(*(arr+i)); j++)
        {

            mat[i][j] = 'a'+ (*(arr+i))-1;
            printf("mat[%d][%d] = %c\n", i, j, mat[i][j]);
        }
      }


}

int main()
{

    int a[] = {3, 4, 5, 2, 3};
    int n = 5;
    letters(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```

My final goal is to make the function print a matrix with 5 rows on which it will print the corresponding letter from array a, that same amount of times. For example line 1, will have letter 'c' printed 3 times, line 2 will have 'd' printed 4 times etc.
For now I just want to print the matrix (i know the rest is not completely implemented, but I want to see what i have so far). it will show me that :

```
m[0][0] = 'c'
m[0][1] = 'c'
m[0][2] = 'c'
m[1][0] = 'd'
m[1][1] = 'd'
m[1][2] = 'd'
m[1][3] = 'd'
```

but then it cracks. Why?

Comment: This looks like a question about C code. Hence, I removed the [tag:c++]. (The community is a bit sensitive about this.)

Comment: O.T.: `malloc()` returns `void*`. There is no cast necessary as `void*` is implicitly casted to any typed pointer.

Comment: O.T.: `*(arr + i)` is identical to `arr[i]` while the latter is little bit easier to read.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Consider splitting the allocation and algorithm into two different functions, to make the code readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the second `for` loop inside your `letters` function, where you *should* be allocating a `char*` pointer to ***each element*** of `mat`:

```c
for (int i=0; i<nr_elem; i++)
{
//    *mat=(char*)malloc((*(arr+i))*sizeof(char)); // *mat keeps getting overwritten!
    mat[i] = malloc((*(arr+i))*sizeof(char)); // Allocates new block for each loop
}
```

In your code, your only ever assign the return from `malloc` to the *first* element of the `mat` array - each loop just overwrites the previously assigned value (i.e. `*mat` is the same as `mat[0]`).

Also, please see this post on (not) casting the return value of `malloc`: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)